# Are multiple nullable foreign keys a bad design?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework-core

We have a table to store user financial transactions.

A transaction can be incremental or decremental, we have 3 types of transactions, increase with a payment, increase with receiving of a gift, and decrease with purchase of product, So our transaction table contains 3 foreign keys:

```
[PaymentId]   [GiftId]   [RequestId]
```

Is this a bad design? What better alternative is there?

I think it is complicated to join `[Transaction]` table with 3 other tables to get details of each transaction to display list of user transactions

Comment: I assume you have a check constraint to ensure only one column has value. Not necessarily bad, it depends how different these things are. Another option is that you could instead make the three tables into optional relations of `Transaction` (PK is the same as PK of `Transaction` plus a type column).

Comment: Your question doesn't have enough information.  What do the ids refer to?  Why isn't a "type" column sufficient to differentiate these?

Comment: I have a type column.
Each Id refer to a table, Payment table has the payment information, Gift has the gift information, Request table has the purchase information. now we need to get all transactions of a user, with its description. if paymentId is not null, description is payment description, if GiftId is not null, description is gift name, if RequestId is not null, description is purchased Request(Product) name.
Only one of the FKs is not null in same record. @gordon-linoff

Comment: Are those three entities sufficiently different as to necessitate different tables?

Comment: Yes.. @ben-thul

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you'd be better off with a column called something along the lines of `TransactionType` and then just storing the `TransactionTypeId` in a single column as well. Using these two columns you can represent any number of types of `Transactions`. You actually find this common in the financial data world with dimension tables that represent things like Cost Type, etc.